# Getting the cumulative sum of values into Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of values into pandas.

my current `df` looks like this.

```
Start Date
0
NA
NA
0
NA
NA
0
NA
0
NA
0
NA
NA

...



df['Start Date'].value_counts(dropna=False)

NaN     2145
0.0      130
Name: Start Date, dtype: int64
```

Current scenario:

```
df['Month'] = df['Start Date'].where(df['Start Date'] == 0, df['Start Date'].shift() + 1)
```

but, it does not work. My result does not match what the output I am looking for.

Expected output:

```
Month
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
...
```

Can someone please help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you provide an input example and the expected output, please?

Comment: @Corralien thank you for your interest in solving this problem. I have updated my question with Input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly your problem but maybe the following could work:

```
df['Month'] = df.groupby(df['Start Date'].eq('0').cumsum()).cumcount()
print(df)

# Output
   Start Date  Month
0           0      0
1          NA      1
2          NA      2
3           0      0
4          NA      1
5          NA      2
6           0      0
7          NA      1
8           0      0
9          NA      1
10          0      0
11         NA      1
12         NA      2
```